# Количество дней от нулевого года до сегодня

Tags: java, android, дата

Как можно узнать количество дней, которое прошло от "начала времен" (0 год, 1 месяц, 1 день) до сегодня?

Comment: 0 год не существует в григорианском и юлинаском календарях, после 1 года до нашей эры сразу идёт 1 год нашей эры. Уточните, какой именно «0 год» вам нужен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант, который я нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165708/3978990):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(0, 1, 1);
long diff = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - cal.getTime().getTime();
System.out.println ("Days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

Есть вариант с [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(0, 1, 1, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
int days = Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays();
```

Answer (score -1):

В лобовую:

```
int days=System.currentTimeMillis()/(24*60*60*1000L);
```

Comment: `currentTimeMillis` возвращает миллисекунды не от 0, а от 1970 года

Comment: Конечно знаю, а ТС, что что просил?